# require.context causing JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm running the following line to get de-centralised routing configuration for a project

```
require.context('../../../..', true,
    /^.*\/resources\/assets\/js\/plugin\.routes\.js$/).keys()
```

webpack appears to compile this successfully, saying 'Build Successful', after spitting out the following line during the build

```
10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...ces\/assets\/js\/plugin\.routes\.js$/
```

Logging the output of the `require.context` works successfully, giving `["./acorn_coursemanagement/resources/assets/js/plugin.routes.js"]`. There is only one route file in the project at the moment, and this is working as expected.

However webpack starts the following process immediately after saying 'Build Successful'

```
WAIT  Compiling...          13:06:07
10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...ces\/assets\/js\/plugin\.routes\.js$/
```

After hanging for ~2 minutes, the webpack process spits out the following information

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4712:0x102801e00]   222922 ms: Mark-sweep 1242.9 (1494.6) -> 1242.7 (1496.1) MB, 1928.8 / 1.6 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[4712:0x102801e00]   224801 ms: Mark-sweep 1242.7 (1496.1) -> 1242.7 (1450.6) MB, 1878.7 / 1.9 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[4712:0x102801e00]   226709 ms: Mark-sweep 1242.7 (1450.6) -> 1242.7 (1446.1) MB, 1907.9 / 1.7 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3639fc25739 <JSObject>
    1: set(this=0x3632dda7401 <Map map = 0x3630c7048d9>,0x363aa0f39e1 <String[126]: /Users/xxxxx/code/pursuit/acorn-seed/local/acorn_shared/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/verror/tests/tst.inherit.js>,0x3631fc76051 <JSArray[1]>)
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/Users/xxxxx/code/pursuit/acorn-seed/local/acorn_shared/node_modules/webpack/lib/ContextModuleFactory.js:~...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 2: node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap, 2>::Rehash(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap>, int) [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Runtime_MapGrow(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x8361ce042fd
 8: 0x8361ceb251e
```

and the process crashes.

I am running a similar process in a smaller project and the build is working successfully. For context there are 820551 files in the project where the process is crashing.

I am wondering why the build works successfully, as indicated by the successful log and webpack notifying 'Build Successful', then immediately re-runs the same process and crashes.

I think it may have something to do with running webpack in `watch` mode, as a one off build works successfully, whereas the watch seems to re-trigger the failing build.